# How to delete and replace a block of text with spaces?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-block, whitespace

## What I want to do

I want to select a block of text in Vim, delete it, and replace the selected block with spaces.

## Example

Suppose I have the following text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Fusce facilisis arcu 
porta leo efficitur malesuada. In eget 
turpis erat. Sed ipsum metus, malesuada 
bibendum ipsum vel, molestie convallis nisi.
```

Suppose I wish to remove the block of text indicated by the hyphens:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing el------sce facilisis arcu 
porta leo eff------ malesuada. In eget 
turpis erat. ------sum metus, malesuada 
bibendum ipsum vel, molestie convallis nisi.
```

How could I turn the original paragraph into the following?

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing el      sce facilisis arcu 
porta leo eff       malesuada. In eget 
turpis erat.       sum metus, malesuada 
bibendum ipsum vel, molestie convallis nisi.
```

## My Understanding

I understand how to select a block of text in Vim: I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to enable Visual block mode, then use arrow keys to outline/select the block.

I can also delete a selected block by pressing <kbd>d</kbd>.

However, I don't know how to replace the text with spaces quickly (without manually inserting each in insert mode, or manually adding them in a way similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676690/1180930)), or whether there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

You can replace every character of your selection with one of your choosing by using `r`, the replace command.

In your case, in visual mode, type

```
r<space>
```